# How to load content via AJAX in a Twitter Bootstrap modal window?

Tags: php, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework2

I'm working within Zend Framework 2 and following this [tutorial](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/zend-framework-2-using-zend-form-and-ajax/) to display and handle form submission via AJAX. Instead of using a jQuery UI modal, I'm using the modal from Twitter Bootstrap 3.

To begin with, I'm just trying to load some dummy content in the modal by specifying a path to a [controller action](http://pastebin.com/DjjTN6ZH) in the href attribute of the [modal trigger](http://pastebin.com/kQt6j0YK) button.

The [view file](http://pastebin.com/u1WnsbHe) for the AJAX action I call contains dummy html.

When I click on 'Add Agency', the page darkens but no modal window is displayed although the dummy html does appear in the top left corner of the page. I'm expecting a Twitter Bootstrap modal window to be displayed along with the dummy html within it. When I remove the href tag from the modal trigger button, the modal displays fine.

Appreciate if anyone can help me achieve this simple aim of loading content in the Twitter Bootstrap modal window.

Comment: Where ever you are inserting the dummy html, it is breaking the markup required for the modal. Open your developer tools, and inspect the generated html, compare it to what Bootstrap specifies, adjust accordingly. A jsfiddle would help if you want any more detailed advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason my dummy HTML wasn't being displayed within the modal window was because I wrote the HTML markup for the modal div, along with its inner divs for the header, body and footer sections of the modal. I wrongly assumed that the content I call via AJAX will be inserted into the modal-body div, however the HTML doest not get injected in the modal-body div and because the markup for that div already exists, the dummy HTML appears outside of this and breaks the layout.

So I removed all the inner divs within the modal div and moved them into the remote content, so that the HTML I want to return is enclosed in those divs.